# Python: What's the best way to send status bits and timestamps with PySerial

Tags: python, serial-port, status, pyserial

I have done a fair bit of searching and reading around but haven't found an exact clear answer. I am making python application which will communicate with another over the serial port. I have been using PySerial to accomplish this. The types of packets I want to send are status information and data readings.
I am proposing to form of my packets as follows:

```
[ Start Byte ][ Length ][ Message ][ End Byte ][ Checksum ]
```

Although I don't think I need the end byte since have a length in there. Am I correct?

I am thinking of shaping the 'Message' part of the packet for status info like so:

```
[ MsgTypeID ][ PacketID ][ Status Bits ][ Timestamp ]
```

The message ID here is just to differentiate that this is a status packet rather than a data packet. The status information itself is made up of 16 bits, representing the state of a number of subsystems in the sending application. For some of these subsystems, a single bit will provide enough info ('0' to say the subsystem is off/low/false, '1' for on/high/true). Others will require 2 or 3 bits (representing states and such). Prototyping the system up, I have been simply constructing a string concatenating the bits up to form a something like `'1001110101101100'` and sending this out the serial port, with the checksum being a modulo 256 of the status bits.

I am pretty new to Python and serial communication but I know this is probably a waste of bandwidth. I know that PySerial has to send strings but representing each bit as a '0' or '1' like this is using a full string representation for each bit. I was wondering what is the best way to send these bits to reduce the bandwidth?

For example, would I take each 8 bits, convert them to hex and send concatenated hex bytes, as in:

```
'10011101' + '01101100'
```

represented as

```
'\x9d' + '\x6c'
```

or should I send them as ASCII? I've also seen mentions of the Struct module. Should I be going down that route instead?

The other thing I am wondering is how to represent the timestamp parts of the message.

Any help, suggestions you can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, obviously it needs one byte per character sent, so if you can encode your data as an ascii string (`str` in Python 2, `bytes` in Python 3), that's most efficient.

The [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct) module is definitely a good idea: it packs Python data into a string (and unpacks it at the other end). That'll work for your timestamps; pack them as whatever type of int or long seems appropriate (see the linked documentation for your options).

struct doesn't do individual bits, though, so you'll have to do that yourself. I've built a dictionary before to translate characters into groups of eight `True`/`False` values:

To decode:

```
pot = [2**x for x in range(8)]  # Powers of 2 (bytes with one 1 and seven 0s)
bitvalues = {}
for x in range(256):
    bitvalues[chr(x)] = [(x & y) != 0 for y in pot]
```

To make a dictionary for encoding, replace the last line with:

```
bitvalues[tuple((x & y) != 0 for y in pot)] = chr(x)
```

If you want to encode/decode from strings of 1s and 0s instead, replace the bit generating the list/tuple with:

```
"".join("1" if (x&y) else "0" for y in pot)
```

Comment: I'll have a look at the struct module. However, I'm not sure I get what you mean. If I have the bits represented as '11011001', how do I get the encoded character string representation of this (already string represented) binary number?

Comment: Well, my implementation used list of booleans, like `[True, True, False ...`. So, if you want to do it based on strings of 1s and 0s, the last bit will need to be something like: `"".join("1" if (x&y) else "0" for y in pot)`. Also note that the dictionary I built was for decoding (i.e. the receiving end). At the sending end, you'll want to switch the keys and values of the dictionary.

Comment: But that's the thing, I don't want to use strings of 1s and 0s (as I am now). Each string uses a whole byte ('1' as ASCII is \x31). I want to only use one byte to represent 8 of these string represented digits ("bits"). Does that make sense? I just want to maximise the bandwidth.

Comment: @Jack: I've updated the answer. What the code does is to make a dictionary for converting between single bytes (characters) and blocks of eight bits. So to encode it, you'll need to split your bits into blocks of eight, then look them up in the dictionary. I.e. `bitvalues["10001010"]` --> `"Q"`

Comment: Aaah, I see now. Very clever :) Thanks Thomas, Much appreciate!

Comment: @Jack: Cool, good luck. If my answer's solved your problem, you might want to accept it, by clicking the tick symbol to the left. Quite apart from giving me 'reputation' points, a high 'acceptance ratio' encourages people to keep answering your questions.

Comment: Another method I came across was to use chr(int('10001010', 2)), which gives '\x8a' (but not "Q"). I see the value in your method, you're basically pre-computing a lookup dictionary to speed up encoding/decoding on the fly. I'm just having trouble working out why we're producing different values (though only some are different). Hmmm...

Comment: @Thomas: I've only just signed up today but I did plan to. I just wanted to make sure it was working correctly for me. I'm just trying to figure out the issue I have mentioned above.

Comment: @Jack: Due to a quirk of how mine works, it's the other way round (least significant bit first). `chr(int('01010001',2))` gives 'Q'. Obviously that's the way it was stored in the file I was trying to read. It doesn't matter, so long as your encoding and receiving use the same system!

Comment: @Thomas: You have the patience of a saint. Sorry for all the confusion. Thanks for clearing that up :)

Answer (score 0):

How frequently are you expecting to send these updates? If update_frequency * length_of_message is far less than the data rate of the serial connection, then there's very little reason to worry about the efficiency of the data encoding, and you might even consider expanding things out to a more human-readable format, especially when you're getting started.

Comment: Hi Russell. I have only described one type of packet here. This status info will only be sent once every second. However, there are also data packets which I would like to send 100 times/second. I need maximum data throughput rather than most more human readability so I need to get ad much transferred as possible. Thanks